# How do i add link button column in data grid in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datagrid, grid

I am trying to add a column of the link button in DataGrid. When I click button an event (method) should call. Please help as I am new to it. Thanks

```
      <asp:DataGrid ID="grdNipr" runat="server" CssClass="dataTable" AllowPaging="true"                                                                                                      
            <Columns>

     <asp:ButtonColumn Text="Approve" ButtonType="PushButton"   HeaderText="Approve" 
      CommandName="ApproveButton" /> 

       </Columns>                                 
       </asp:DataGrid>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You are more likely to get a response if you include what steps you have tried and where you have looked for help.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Comment: please share with us your workout, code snippets, error logs, or any useful information to help answer your question.